# How do I create a file download popup form?

Tags: 7, files

I am new to drupal, and I want to create a popup form with with form fields for name and email, and a buttom to download and to close the popup.

When users click on the download link, the popup form appears; users enter their name and email address; once the data have been validated, the users can download the file, and see how many users downloaded it.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Email Download](http://drupal.org/project/email_download) does just what you want.

> A tiny module to make downloads only available to people who submit their email address to the site in case the site creator doesn't want visitors to be required to create an account. The email is checked for validity and a cookie with a hard to guess authentication string is stored in a browser cookie. The next time (and of course this first time) the user makes a download, the cookie is checked and the user can proceed. This of course requires cookies to be on on the client side.

Comment: but this module only available for drupal6

Comment: You didn't specify Drupal Version. Search for similar module available for your version, or take this code and port it. Or use it as an example how to do it when writing your own module.